# Shiro+Guice+Chrome, JSESSIONID Cookie is reset on every request

Tags: google-chrome, react-redux, guice, shiro, jsessionid

I am really desperated now because I am not able to figure out the problem for hours. I nearly finished constructing my webapp based on Apache Shiro, Google Guice, Jersey REST and in the frontend react+redux. Until today it really worked fine on Google Chrome, but suddenly Chrome is not able to hold the session because the JSESSIONID changes on every request. I am not able to figure out the problem, Firefox on the other hand works fine. This is really confusing for me. I searched the web for possible solutions and was able to find this problem but none of the provided solutions worked for me.

I made a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvwxu.png) of the requests in the browser. The first REST requests are working fine, then for some reason a favicon.ico file is requested which sets a new JSESSIONID. From then on the session is lost. I do not know where the request may come from. I never use favicons...

If you need additional information please let me know! I would be so thankful if someone can point me in the right direction. I am sitting here for hours trying to solve the problem.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Oh my god, after hours of researching I found the problem and it was the favicon request which only failed on Chrome. Problem have been the jetty redirect rules in my case. I had the following rule:

```
    <Call name="addRule">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteRegexRule">
                <Set name="regex">^(?:(?!\/rest\/|\/resources\/|\/login).)*$</Set>
                <Set name="replacement">/sua-ui/resources/secure/index.jsp</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
```

which I changed now to

```
    <Call name="addRule">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteRegexRule">
                <Set name="regex">^(?:(?!\/rest\/|\/resources\/|\/login|favicon).)*$</Set>
                <Set name="replacement">/sua-ui/resources/secure/index.jsp</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
```

This means excluding the favicon from redirects solved my problem, but why the failed favicon request set a new JSESSIONID cookie I really don't know. Happy that my app works again!